# C++/Java Sockets automatic Port allocation

Tags: java, c++, sockets, port

I've a server (Java) and a number of clients (c++), connected by sockets.
I would like to set the ports automatically.
Assuming the IP is already known.

In the Java side I can make :

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(0);
```

So now I've a random free port on the server.

How can I know in the C++ side, what port is the server listening to?

Comment: It can not know the server's port number, how should it? You could try to let the client scan the servers ports, but what should that good for?

Answer (score 3):

I think is not possible, if you want establish a connection with a server, you must know in which port is the server listening, there are programs like nmap that shows you a list of opened ports in a server, but a server can have many opened ports at the same time and then, How do you know what is the port opened by your server? and in any case, is too slow and inefficient to call external tool, read and parse its output. For what reason do you need a random port service?

Other option can be get the opened socket in the server side calling to `s.getLocalPort()` and send it via UDP for any listening node in the network with broadcasting, and re-program the client side to listen in broadcast and when it receives a message, check if it is a port number and connect to the server using that port.

Comment: Broadcasting is an option, just keep in mind that broadcasts are (usually) not forwarded by routers across LAN boundaries, so it would only work if all clients are on the same LAN segment.

Comment: @Joan Lledó I don't want to hard-code the port in the c++ clients, because I don't know how many of them I will have. I may want to connect more, at any time.

Comment: @pap They are on the same computer actually. How do I make that happen.

Comment: @IsocketThis - you are aware that more than one client can connect to the same port, right? You don't have to have separate listening ports on the server for each client. And if you are dynamically adding more listening ports to your server (hard to understand why without knowing what your app does), just have ONE hardcoded port that clients connect to, respond with all other active ports and have the clients take appropriate action. See my answer regarding "locator" service. You will need EITHER broadcast OR a fixed, known port to a locator service. Those are the options available.

Comment: Hard-coding, or configuring to a fixed value, the server port to connect to in the client won't stop you from having an arbitrary number of clients.

Comment: @IsocketThis like @pap says, A port and a connection are not the same thing, there may be many connections in the same port simultaneously. You can write a infinite loop running `s.accept()` and write a new `Runnable` class that process the request in a separated thread.

Comment: So.. in your opinions what would the best way?
just have a port that makes the first communication to inform of the real port?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not reliably. In IP, a machine is identified by an address. A server (ie, a service) is identified by an address and a port. You clients need some form of "known service" that they can connect to.

If you, for whatever reason, absolutely want to have dynamic listening port, you could combine it with a "locator" service on a known port. For instance, have a web service/servlet on the standard http port (80). Your clients connect to the "locator" service (always on port 80) and asks which port your application is currently listening on. This is a not entirely uncommon pattern. RMI works is a similar way where you have a registry on a known port. Clients connect to the registry and asks for the location of RMI endpoints.